# Sqlite: Implementing a routine to rename columns including datatypes

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I asked a similar question before but I did not get the answer I am looking for. I need some help with implementing rename columns (including datatypes) in Sqlite.

I am aware of the overall steps but need help to deal with various datatype conversions.
1) ALTER TABLE table to table_backup
2) CREATE the required table "table" with renamed columns (datatype)
3) INSERT INTO table using select from table_backup
4) DROP table_backup

Say if I am converting from double to integer, how do I truncate data? Converting double to integer is just one scenario. How to implement other datatype conversions? I am programming in C# if that helps.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert from double to integer, use `CAST`:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(a, b, c) SELECT a, CAST(b AS INTEGER), c FROM MyTableBackup
```

`CAST` also [supports other data types](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr), like `TEXT` and `REAL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about about data type conversions? say Integer to Boolean. If I use cast, then the integer values remain. Is this conversion supported?  I am looking for a list of data type conversions that are supported and needs to be implemented.

Comment: SQLite does not have a native boolean type; it uses integers 0 and 1. Use an expression like `myvalue <> 0`.

Comment: So, just to clarify you are saying while converting Integer to Boolean, see if the integer value is not equal to 1?? Should I check if the value is > 1, if yes, store 0 (as default). I am sorry, I am a newbie and need additional clarification. That took care of two datatype conversions - Double to Integer and Integer to Boolean? What about others like Integer to Text , Text to Integer, Boolean to Real etc which is not making much sense to convert. Should those be implemented ? Also should the CAST be used for all datatype conversions?

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated and apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: What to check for booleans depends on the meaning of those values. Use `CAST` for all types supported by it; see the doc I linked.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to implement Rename. I have so far implemented Drop, Rename, Add and reorder columns. However I am running some tests to find out in what order should these routines be called? Should drop column be called first always? Is the order DROP RENAME ADD REORDER columns? Any thoughts?

Comment: The order does not matter for the end result. Just use the one that is fastest.

Comment: I think there was a miscommunication. I am not referring to the order in which columns are renamed and inserted but the order in which the routines DROP columns RENAME columns ADD columns and REORDER columns should be called. This thread talks about rename only, however I have other routines implemented and was wondering if there's a recommended order to call these routines. Thanks very much for your willingness to help!